# Interview - find greater element for each array`s element

Tags: arrays, algorithm, compare

I was asked the following question during the interview (Unfortunately I couldn't find the answer better than N^2)

For a given array `arr` for `unsigned int` of size N,for each element (in the index `i`) I should return an element in the index `j` (j > i),such that `arr[j] > arr[i]`
I.e. I should return array res in which res[i] has a arr[j],j>i,arr[j] > arr[i],j is min among all indices k ,such that arr[k] > arr[i]
for example

```
arr[] = {3,1,4,2,5,7};
res[] = {2,2,4,4,5,-1};//-1 says no such index
```

Any proposition to do it in better time complexity?
Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just sort the array and then look at the next element? Any sort that executes in less than N^2 should do.

Comment: Shouldn't res be {2,3,4,4,5,-1};

Comment: res[] is flawed in your example. You say res[i] contains arr[j]. However you have arr[0] = 3 and res[0] = 2 but 2 < 3. EDIT: Nevermind, greedy algorithm can't be used for min index.

Comment: Can the elements repeat, or are they unique?

Comment: Shouldn't res be {4, 4, 5, 5, 7, -1}

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element/

Comment: @MichalWegorek It's index, not value - `arr[2] = 4`.

Comment: @Dukeling "should return array res in which res[i] has a arr[j]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**O(n) algorithm:**

Maintain a stack of indexes that are still not solved. This will be sorted so that the minimum still unsolved value is on the top. As you reach a new element pop from the stack until the value of the new element is less than the value on top of the stack. For each that you pop, the answer is the current index. Then push on the current index. At the end, the result for anything still on the stack is -1.

Code (C++):

```
stack<int> unsolved;
int arr[] = {3,1,4,2,5,7}, N = 6;
int res[1234];

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        while (!unsolved.empty() && arr[unsolved.top()] < arr[i]) {
            res[unsolved.top()] = i;
            unsolved.pop();
        }
        unsolved.push(i);
    }
    while (!unsolved.empty()) {
        res[unsolved.top()] = -1;
        unsolved.pop();
    }
    // Print results
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%d%c", res[i], i==N-1 ? '\n' : ' ');

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 2 4 4 5 -1
```

Comment: I don't think this is O(n). You have two nested loops.

Comment: That is a very simplistic way to analyse time complexity. If you think about it, every element is pushed once, and every time the inner loop runs an element is popped, so it will only run at maximum N times.

Comment: Yes you are right. I misread the question as min(arr[j]) instead of min(j). +1 :)

Answer (score 6):

**O(N) Time and O(N) Space Complexity:**

Create empty stack, iterate the array from the right

for each iterated item: 
keep popping from the stack as long as item on the top is smaller than current, then if the stack becomes empty there's no bigger element on the right, if not that's your first bigger item on the right for current element, push current item on the stack

```
void GetFirstRight(int* arr, int size, int* res){
  stack<int> s;
  for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    while (!s.empty() && s.top() <= arr[i]) s.pop();
    if (s.empty()) { 
      res[i] = -1;
    } else {
      res[i] = s.top();
    }
    s.push(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is O(n). You have two nested loops.

Comment: Let's analyze it: how many times the inner loop will iterate for 1 function call? Answer: Maximum number of times is the value of size. We insert items only once.

Comment: But in popping out elements I feel you may lose those items from the stack that may be important for future elements.

Comment: Analyze again: we're droppinig items not needed in the future

Comment: Would this work for a = { 4,5,8,7 }? when you reach element 5, then element 7 will not be in the stack because it will be popped out by 8.

Comment: That's right, when you reach 8, 7 won't be in res array for any element on the left from 8, so 7 will be popped even sooner - when we reach 8

Comment: Yes you are right. I misread the question as min(arr[j]) instead of min(j). +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep a parallel array **b**. make **b[0]=0**.
Make a run to iterate thru the elements of **a**. as you go along, set the values of **b** to the differences of consecutive cells of **a**.

so, if

```
a[0]=9
a[1]=4
a[2]=17
a[3]=2
a[4]=3
a[5]=6
a[6]=0
a[7]=3
a[8]=1
a[9]=1
a[10]=7
```

then,

```
b[0]=0
b[1]=-5
b[2]=13
b[3]=-15
b[4]=1
b[5]=3
b[6]=-6
b[7]=3
b[8]=-2
b[9]=0
b[10]=6
```

All you should be concerned about is the (-) cells in the **b** array.
Now, start iterating backwards on array **b**-- starting from 
**b[10]** in the above eg. 
Keep a **currentMax** value. initially set to the first max (+) 
on the array-- nothing you can do about the (-) entries at the end of the array.
As you iterate backwards from **b[b.length]** down to **b[0]**, do the following:

update **currentMax**:

```
currentMax += <value at the current cell of **b**>
```

if **(currentMax<0)** then /* you've hit elements-with-no-indexes*/ then keep going till you find a positive **b[i]** entry, and when you find one, set the value of **currentMax** to it.

(+) values of **currentMax** indicate cells that the cell that reset **currentMax** is the index for all cells visited-so-far, (-) values are no-index cells.

In the above eg, 7 at **a[10]** is the index of all in **a[3]..a[9]**, because 
-**currentMax** is the one initialized at cell 10 (and not reset afterwards)
-the value of **currentMax** after all those additions is still (+) all the way up to cell 4 (cell 4 reflects the change from cell 3-to-4)

At **b[3]**, **currentMax** falls below 0--meaning no index for cell 2.
The value found at **b[2]** is positive while **currentMax** is negative-- so make at b[3], **currentMax=13** and iterate on.

Linear in the array size-- takes **O(n)** time.